# Store looped data in separate variables?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables, foreach

I'm currently using the following in my `single.php` file to list the parent category and child category that my posts belong to:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    echo '<h1>'.$category->cat_name . '</h1>'; 
}
```

So this results in:
`<h1>Events</h1><h1>News</h1>`

**However, I would like to store each `<h1>` value in a separate variable.**

So my eventual code could be:

```
$i1 = "<h1>Events</h1>"; 
$i2 = "<h1>News</h1>";
```

How do I do this?

Comment: An array would be a much cleaner, easier and faster way to do this. Is there any reason you'd prefer to use variable variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use a "variable variable":

```
$j = 1;
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    $i{$j} = '<h1>' . $category->cat_name . '</h1>';
    $j++;
}
```

However, I would just use an array:

```
$i = array();
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    $i[] = '<h1>' . $category->cat_name . '</h1>'; 
}
```

Comment: Brilliant -- many thanks!! I had been working on this most of the afternoon and couldn't see where I went wrong.
It was the curly brackets I missed. I used square :'(
`Thank you!!!`

Comment: You DONT want to use variable variables! They are from hell and will lead to many problems later, because they are code generated and interpreted at runtime, which is really hard to debug. Always use arrays instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` to return all `cat_name` to array ... you can also use list to seprate them to 2 different variables

```
# List Of Name form array
$categories = array_map(function($category){ return "<h1>" . $category->cat_name . "</h1>";}, get_the_category());

# List Name to diffrent varraibles 
list($i1,$i2) = $categories ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$n = 0;
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    $i{$n} = '<h1>'.$category->cat_name . '</h1>'; 
    $n++;
}
```

[Take a look at this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). This is weird though and would probably make your code confusing (and I wouldn't recommend doing it like this. Why not use an array instead?

```
$categories = array();
$n = 0;
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    $categories[$n] = '<h1>'.$category->cat_name . '</h1>';
    $n++;
}
```